# What does inconsistent number of samples mean?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm using scikit's logistic regression but I keep getting the message:

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [90000, 5625]
```

In the code below, I've removed the columns with text in them and then I've split the date into a training and testing set.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset = pd.read_csv("/Users/An/Desktop/data/telco.csv", na_values = ' ') 
dataset = dataset.dropna(axis = 0)

dataset = dataset.replace({'Yes':1, 'Fiber optic': 1, 'DSL':1, 'No':0, 'No phone service':0, 'No internet service':0})
dataset = dataset.drop('Contract', axis  =1)
dataset = dataset.drop('PaymentMethod',axis  =1)
dataset = dataset.drop('customerID',axis  =1)
dataset = dataset.drop('gender',axis  =1)

for i in list(['tenure', 'MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges']):
    sd = np.std(dataset[i])
    mean = np.mean(dataset[i])
    dataset[i] = (dataset[i] - mean) / sd

total = pd.DataFrame(dataset)  
data_train, data_test = train_test_split(total, test_size=0.2)
data_train = data_train.values
data_test = data_test.values

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = LogisticRegression(C=1e9)
clf = clf.fit(data_train[:,0:16], data_train[:,16])
print clf.intercept_, clf.coef_
```

Could someone please explain what the error message means and help me figure out why I'm getting it?

Comment: Could you post the shape of `data_train`?

Comment: @markuscosinus I've put it under Chris's answer

Answer (score 1):

In the second last line, `data_train.reshape(-1, 1)` is causing your problem. Removing `reshape` will do you a favor.

### Reason

`LogisticRegression.fit` is expecting `x` and `y` to have same `shape[0]`, but you are reshaping your `x` from `(n, m)` to `(n*m, 1)`.

Here is the reproduced shapes:

```
import numpy as np

df = np.ndarray((2000,10))
x, y  = df[:, 2:9], df[:, 9]
x.shape, y.shape # << what you should give to `clf.fit`
# ((2000, 7), (2000, ))

x.reshape(-1, 1).shape, y.shape # << what you ARE giving to `clf.fit`,
# ((14000, 1), (2000,))         # << which is causing the problem
```

Comment: I removed the reshape and now the shape of the two arrays is (5625, 16) and (5625,), which is fine. But I'm now getting this error: ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'.

Comment: @Anya That's when `y` doesn't have uniform `dtype`. I cannot pin-point the reason as I don't have the dataset, but my guess is that when you do `dataset.replace`, there are some items that wasn't transformed into `int`. You can check by `dataset.iloc[-1].value_counts()`.

Comment: Even though I specified the x values to be the data in columns 2 to 18, it seems that my code was still reading columns 0 and 1, which contain text. After I dropped the first two columns my code ran fine. Do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: @Anya Can you please update your question to reflect your current code?

Comment: I've updated it - my dataset now has only 16 columns